# First Python Program

Tags: python

I am trying to make a basic program that gets the name from a user and makes a "lucky number" by just adding a number based on if it greater or less than another number. What am i doing wrong here?

```py
    myName = input('Insert name: ')
    myLuckynumber = int(input('Insert a number 1-9: '))
    if myLuckynumber > 5:
        Newlucky = int(myLuckynumber + 3)
        print('Hello '+myName+'your lucky number is: '+Newlucky)
    elif myLuckynumber < 5:
        newLucky = int(myLuckynumber + 4)
        print('Hello '+myName+'your lucky number is: '+newLucky)
    else:
        print('try again!')
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive headline

Comment: Welcome to Python! You are going to have fun. Adding input() which returns str to int will give problem to you. Also, please read about https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "What am i doing wrong here?"—you tell us. Are you getting an error message? Unexpected behaviour? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a `str` to an `int`, they need to be strings to concatenate

```
print('Hello '+myName+'your lucky number is: '+ str(Newlucky))
```

Or using something like `str.format`

```
print('Hello {} your lucky number is: {}'.format(myName, Newlucky))
```